# How can I assign class for more than one tags?

Tags: html, css

something like:

html:

```
<tr class = "foo"> 
   <td class = "foo"> ... </td>
   <td class = "foo"> ... </td>
</tr>
```

stylesheet :

```
// I want to merge these
tr.foo { ... } 
td.foo { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine rulesets in CSS using a comma:

```
tr.foo, td.foo { /* all these rules apply to both */ }
```

This of course does not preclude you from having other rulesets including another `tr.foo` or `td.foo`, or overwriting rules in the cascade.

If you want to use the descendant selector, it's just a space:

```
tr.foo td.foo { /* affects all td class=foo children of tr class=foo */ }
```

There is also the more specific child selector `>`

Answer (score 3):

just use `.foo{/*styles in here*/}` there is no need to specify the tag

Comment: Well, unless you're trying to specify the tag.

Comment: based on the title it doesn't look like that is the case though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id="trow" >
  <td id="tcol">...</td>
  <td id="tcoll">..</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
#trow,#tcol,#tcoll { 
-------------
-------------
}
```

The class name you mentioned are same..

```
foo {
---------
---------
}
```

is enough. need not to merge if the style is same..